# ImageReader Access violation with release config in gdcm

Tags: gdcm

I want to use the x64 gdcm library in my c++ app and it works in debug builds, But when i make a build with release configuration then i have :

Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

When calling `getDataSet()` function :

```
gdcm::File &file = reader.GetFile();
gdcm::DataSet dataset = file.GetDataSet();
```

Can anyone help me to i fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Didi you build the GDCM yourself, or use a binary distributed version?

Comment: @Trantor, I did both of them, they are same.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok with your file object (and its reference), then
the right way to call GetDataSet method seems to be:

```
const gdcm::DataSet &ds = file.GetDataSet();
```

So you get the reference to the internals and don't try to copy them; at least this is how it works in my code.